# Method Overriding with classes and interfaces

Tags: java, class, interface

If a class A and an interface I have methods of the same signature, which method is overridden when a class B extends class A, implements interface I and provides a method of the same signature as A and I? P.S I have checked different places but none mentioned what happens if that method is also overridden in the subclass, i.e. which method it's overriding

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: like tested it?

Comment: If you test it, you will find out c;

Comment: if so yes, but i couldn't figure out a way to find out whether it's the interface method or the super class method it overrode

Comment: If you could just assist me with this, i will be grateful

Comment: Just make sure that every method print something different which allows you to distinguish the methods

Comment: That's what i said earlier, if i override the method in the subclass it prints what i put in that method but there is still no way to know if that method overrode the super class or the interface

Comment: What i'm asking is does that method override the super class method or interface method

Answer (score 1):

It overrides the method of class A.
Methods of interfaces are implemented, not overridden.

Comment: The @Override annotation on interface methods can be a bit confusing.

Comment: I understand that, forgive my misuse of terms. so you're saying that it is not an implementation of an abstract method that takes place but an override of a super class method?

Comment: Class `A` implements the method of interface `I`. Class `B` overrides the method of class `A` and contemporarily implements the method of interface `I`.

Answer (score 0):

Class B extends A ; 
Then methods class B with same method signature as class A are overides.

When class B implements I;
Methods declared in the interface has to be implemented in the class B.